# Instant crash with the use of a custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I never used custom view before, so most likely I am doing something wrong.

Below is my Java code for my `SmartTabLayout` class that supposed to switch between `MODE_FIXED` and `MODE_SCROLLABLE` based on total combined width of all its tabs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SmartTabLayout extends android.support.design.widget.TabLayout {

    public SmartTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SmartTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SmartTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (getTabCount() == 0) return;
        try {
            ViewGroup tabLayout = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
            int combinedWidth = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
                combinedWidth += tabLayout.getChildAt(i).getMeasuredWidth();
            setTabMode(combinedWidth <= getMeasuredWidth() ? MODE_FIXED : MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My layout XML file contains the following part:

```
<SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right" />

</SmartTabLayout>
```

When (in my XML file) I change `SmartTabLayout` to `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`, all works normal, but with no "smart" feature that is desired. So I assume the XML code is fine. But when I use my `SmartTabLayout` in the XML file, the app crashes right after launch. Debugger doesn't even call a single line of my custom code. What am I missing?

---

Logs (below) includes the following message:

> Didn't find class "android.view.SmartTabLayout" on path...

Should I somewhere explicitly point to my custom view class?

```
    02-16 15:56:14.328 24316-24316/? E/Zygote: v2
    02-16 15:56:14.328 24316-24316/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10327
    02-16 15:56:14.328 24316-24316/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    02-16 15:56:14.330 24316-24316/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
    02-16 15:56:14.331 24316-24316/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 SPD:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0006 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0010, [-1 -1 -9 -1 0 1]
    02-16 15:56:14.332 24316-24316/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.android 
    02-16 15:56:14.339 24316-24316/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    02-16 15:56:14.381 24316-24316/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
    02-16 15:56:14.381 24316-24316/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
    02-16 15:56:14.406 24316-24316/com.example.android W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.android is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    02-16 15:56:14.409 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
    02-16 15:56:15.420 24316-24323/com.example.android I/art: Debugger is active
    02-16 15:56:15.611 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    02-16 15:56:15.611 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:15.811 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:16.012 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:16.212 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:16.412 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:16.613 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:16.813 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    02-16 15:56:17.013 24316-24316/com.example.android I/System.out: debugger has settled (1370)
    02-16 15:56:17.112 24316-24316/com.example.android W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android-2/lib/arm64
    02-16 15:56:17.129 24316-24316/com.example.android D/ContextRelationMgrBrdg: loadKlass() : caller=com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.<clinit>:28 com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.getInstance:-1 
    02-16 15:56:17.139 24316-24316/com.example.android I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    02-16 15:56:17.210 24316-24316/com.example.android W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    02-16 15:56:17.315 24316-24316/com.example.android D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    02-16 15:56:17.316 24316-24316/com.example.android D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    02-16 15:56:17.348 24316-24316/com.example.android D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-16 15:56:17.354 24316-24316/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android, PID: 24316
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class SmartTabLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class SmartTabLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class SmartTabLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SmartTabLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.android.Main.onCreate(Main.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)02-16 15:56:17.355 24316-24316/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime:
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: what r ur logs?

Comment: What about calling this in another activity, so you can atleast attempt to debug?

Comment: Are you using fully qualified name of your customView? including the package.

Comment: @DroiDev - Logs have been added to the post.

Comment: you have to use it a `<com.your.[ackage.SmartTabLayout`. Only android-native views can be used without package.

Comment: Big THANK YOU to everyone who comments this post.

Comment: can u try to take the SmartTabLayout as the child with parent layout and mention the SmartTabLayout according to Viad mat comment <com.your.[ackage.SmartTabLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many of us thought, change of `<SmartTabLayout>` to `<com.example.android.SmartTabLayout>` would make a trick.

But it wasn't enough to make it work. I had to add:

```
package com.example.android;
```

at the beginning of my `SmartTabLayout` class file. Now it works, but it shows a warning

> Package name 'com.example.android' does not correspond to the file
>   path ''

So I have to move my Java class source code from `...\java` directory to `...\java\com.example.android` folder and now it works without warnings.

That move of file makes sense, because I had added `package com.example.android;`.

But why I had to make this custom view a part of my package to make it work? Shouldn't that work even outside of the package? Weird. But as I wrote, this is/was my first experience with the custom view, so I have learned something.

Hopefully it will help others who experience same issue.

Comment: Wasn't your custom view class in the same package as the layout it was being used in?

Your code in the question doesn't show which package the custom view was but assuming  

it was in com.example , if you want to use your custom view in any layout in your project, you would implement it as <com.example.SmartTabLayout.../>

Comment: @ViVekH  Thanks. Lesson learned. BTW - a full name has to be used, so in my case it is `<com.example.android.SmartTabLayout>`

Comment: Just curious, glad you fixed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The logs point to an

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SmartTabLayout"
```

Error, Try changing your layout to

```
<<package_name>.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"

.../>
```

Comment: I thought same, but it wasn't enough. There is some problem with path, but it is on Android Studio, I assume.

Comment: weird, you might have already tried this out but try file->invalidate caches/restart->invalidate, then Build->clean and finally Build->rebuild.

Comment: Yup, I did. Didn't make a difference. But after I moved the file to correct folder, it works without a warning. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score -3):

Try to make the following changes for the super calls for the first two constructors to be like this:

```
public SmartTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public SmartTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SmartTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
```

Comment: I just checked your updated log, it looks like `SmartTabLayout` is not recognized, can you try with full qualified class name? for example: `<com.example.mycustomviews.SmartTabLayout> ... </com.example.mycustomviews.SmartTabLayout>`